# What linux configurations can cause executables to hang when making HTTP/HTTPS requests?

Tags: linux, networking, python

I have a Python application that uses urllib2 to query Facebook graph for certain user information. The solution is deployed on Ubuntu server.

On my development machine the response time is what you would expected from a simple HTTP request. However the production server hangs for around 60 seconds before returning a response.

To test it is not the outgoing connection of the server I have used curl on the exact same URL and the response is quick as expected.

What linux configurations can cause executables to hang when making HTTP/HTTPS requests?

Comment: I'm not sure that this question can be definitively answered.  There are so many ones, certainly there is no limit to BAD configurations.

Comment: Please do not vote to close this question, instead give some pointers on how I can improve the wording of it. This was a painful issue and kasperd has given an in depth answer that could help other people.

Comment: The question "What linux configurations can cause executables to hang when making HTTP/HTTPS requests?" is really very broad.  Editing the question to describe the differences between development and production and asking if one or more of them could be causing the delay might improve the question.

Comment: Rather than asking about specific causes (way too broad, far too many causes), a better approach would be asking assistance in how to *narrow down* the causes of the problem. For example, prefixing the command with `strace -f` would show you the syscall trace and give you a better idea of where the process is hanging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that can go wrong is failing DNS lookups. Those may time out and have to be retried against a different server, but the timeouts tend to be a lot shorter than 60 seconds, so I don' think that is a likely explanation.

Next you need to establish a TCP connection to the server. The server may have multiple IP addresses, so the client will need to decide on some order in which to try them. If addresses are tried sequentially, it is not unlikely to see a 60 second timeout before the client gives up on one IP and moves on to the next.

If the network connection between the client and the first IP address is down, you may consistently see timeouts followed by success once the client switches to the next IP address. This behavior has been seen a lot in setups where client and server have both IPv4 and IPv6 support, but somebody wasn't really paying attention to the IPv6 connectivity and did not repair the setup once the IPv6 connectivity failed for some reason.

The next thing that can go wrong is usually MTU problems. Those tend to cause the connection to stall and eventually time out, but in those cases you don't just continue to the next IP address.

Another thing that could happen is that the server might throttle you, if you are making too many requests.

Comment: it was an IPv6 issue, as a quick fix I have disabled IPv6 on my server. Do you know a more graceful solution?

Comment: @S-K' That is really two different questions. What can be done in the application, and what can be done from a sysadmin point of view? The application question might be more suited for another site, but I can give a brief answer: If it is used for something interactive, then Google the the term "Happy Eyeballs" to get some guidelines, which you need an HTTP library, that supports. If it is not used for anything interactive, then who cares if it takes another minute, as long as it works?

Comment: @S-K' What a sysadmin should do about a broken IPv6 connection is really worth a question on its own. First question is, if one of the two endpoints has completely lost connectivity to the IPv6 backbone. If that is the case, then you have to find the problem with that endpoint and fix it. If both endpoints have connectivity to the backbone, but they consistently cannot communicate with each other, then you need to find which ISP on the path has a problem. It may be a peering dispute, some of those have been going on for years.

Comment: @S-K' Finally there is a very relevant question about how to monitor your network connectivity. You want to know right away if either your IPv4 connection or your IPv6 connection goes down. To make it not sound all bad, remember that dual stack also gives a bit of redundancy. If you screwed up the network configuration of one of the two stacks, there is a chance you can still log on the server using the other protocol and fix the problem.